# Lower bound on probability of choosing odd integer out of $2m$ integers

Tags: probability, upper-lower-bounds

> The probability of choosing an integer ‘$k$’ out of $2m$ integers
> $1,2,3,…2m$ is inversely proportional to $k^4$.If $P_1$ is the probability that chosen number is odd and $P_2$
> is the probability that chosen number is even, then
>
> A. $P_1 < \frac{2}{3}$
>
> B. $P_1 > \frac{1}{2}$
>
> C. $P_1 > \frac{2}{3}$
>
> D. $P_2 < \frac{1}{2}$

It is obvious that B and D are true, since probability of choosing odd number is greater than choosing even number. After trying on for some values of $m$, I feel C is also true, although the official answer is BD. The value of $P_1$ will be $\sum_{r=1} ^ m \frac{x}{(2r-1)^4}$ where $x= \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{2m} k^{-4}}$.

I tried to prove C by taking $\displaystyle{\lim_{m \to \infty}} P_1$ but couldn't compute it. Wolfram Alpha says that it's equal to $\frac{15}{16}$. Is there some other way to prove option C?

Comment: Isn't the probability that $k=1$ is chosen already far larger than $\frac23$?

Comment: @GregMartin Won't it be $\frac{1}{\sum _{k=1}^{2m} k^{-4}}$? How do we prove this is larger than $\frac{2}{3}$ for all m?

Comment: @GregMartin the way that I read the problem, the chance that a specific number $r$ is chosen is $$\frac{r^{(-4)}}{\sum_{k=1}^{2m} k^{(-4)}}.$$ Here, the denominator is used to *normalize* the respective probabilities, so that the sum of all the probabilities $= 1$.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-4} = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes I did realise that using Wolfram. But this question is for high school students without using a calculator. Is there any other way to do it rather than just computing?

Comment: That sort of context is helpful to put into the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $m=1$ you have $P_1 = \frac{\frac1{1^4}}{\frac1{1^4}+\frac1{2^4}} = \frac{16}{17}> \frac23$

Now consider the position as $m \to \infty$.

Let $S_\infty= \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^4}$ so $\frac{S_\infty}{2^4} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)^4}$ and $P_1 \to \frac{S_\infty-\frac{S_\infty}{2^4}}{S_\infty} = \frac{15}{16}> \frac23$ as $n$ increases

This suggests that $C$ is true.  For a proof, you can adjust the previous part:

Let $S_m= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2m} \frac{1}{k^4}$ so $\frac{S_m}{2^4} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2m}  \frac{1}{(2k)^4} > \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}  \frac{1}{(2k)^4}$ so for all $m$ we have $$P_1 = \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2m} \frac{1}{k^4}- \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}  \frac{1}{(2k)^4} }{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2m}  \frac{1}{k^4}} >  \frac{S_m-\frac{S_m}{2^4}}{S_m} = \frac{15}{16}> \frac23.$$